# Vertica, where to include null

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a query that gets the count of my field, but i want to include nulls. I get a count of 10.

```
select in_currency, count(*) from stackoverflow
where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09'
and scenario_set_name ('A','null')
group by in_currency
```

but this count is getting me just total of A, as when i query A and null separately i get different counts.

I get total 10 when I do :

```
select in_currency, count(*) from stackoverflow
where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09'
and scenario_set_name = 'A'
group by in_currency
```

and get 5 when i do :

```
  select in_currency, count(*) from stackoverflow
    where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09'
    and scenario_set_name is null
    group by in_currency
```

I want to combine both, as the total should be 15 when I remove the scenario set name clause.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic in the first query is:

```
where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09' and scenario_set_name in ('A', 'null')
```

This is comparing `scenario_set_name` to the *string* value `'null'`.  This string value is quite distinct from the actual value.

You could try to write this as:

```
where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09' and scenario_set_name in ('A', NULL)
```

But that also will not get `NULL` values, because almost all comparisons to `NULL` return `NULL`, which is treated as "false" in `WHERE` conditions.

You need to include both conditions in the logic:

```
where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09' and
      (scenario_set_name = 'A' or scenario_set_name is NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select in_currency, count(*) from stackoverflow
where bd_business_day = '2018-02-09'
and ( scenario_set_name = 'A' or scenario_set_name is null)
group by in_currency
```